# please explain elements in iphone "add contact" interface

Tags: iphone, tableview, contacts

How could I build something like the "add contact" interface in iphone. 
1. It seems the whole view is a grouped table view with customized cells. Is it correct? 
2. How does it set the "+" and "-" icons on the left side, 
3. How does it implement the "add photo" and name field? It seems they are not in one cell. 
4. The home page row is directly editable in this screen, is it a textfield embedded in a cell? 
5. There are usually a "delete record" button at the end of a tableview in stock applications. Is it a one-cell section covered by a UI Button?

screenshot: http://www.iphone-recovery.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/jcontact.jpg

Comment: No idea if you can do this with the default UITableViewCell, I would definitely subclass for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it seems more like a list of controls UILabel, UITextField inside a scrollview. You can achieve that more easily than customizing a tableviewcell. Name field are set by setting the UITextField.placeholder property.

For scrolling make sure your scrollview's contentsize is bigger than the frame.